Unable to store a pointer to a class in C++
I am coding a model kit collection manager and for that I coded a shell that has a few variables that go like that :
class MonkeyShell {
private:
    bool _exitFlag; // Value that keeps the loop going until we input the command "exit" in terminal.
    std::vector<std::string> _commands; // Vector of commands that we get from the terminal.
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> commandMap; // A map to all of the corresponding command/functions.
    MonkeyManager _manager; // A class that handles file opening, saving, closing etc...
    MonkeyCollection _collection; // The class containing a vector of "MonkeyModels" and the timezone used in the file.
    std::string _level; // what to print on the prompt in the loop.
}

But now, I want to implement a new value, which would "redirect" simply to a MonkeyModel already existing in the _collection when the command "edit" is inputted, that way I can work on a model without having to do copies and copies again, saving some resources.
Having worked with C for my entire first year of school my reflex was adding a variable that goes like : MonkeyModel* _selectedModel in the MonkeyShell class.
Then once that was done I coded an edit function that gets the number of the model you want to edit from _collection, and that looks like that :
void MonkeyShell::editCommand() {
    std::string modelNumberString;
    int modelNumber = 0;
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << "Which model do you want to work on ?" << std::endl << _collection << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, modelNumberString);
    modelNumber = std::stoi(modelNumberString) - 1; // When printing the collection, the models are listed with the first index being 1, so we substract one to fit.
    _selectedModel = &_collection.getModels().at(modelNumber); // Here, we should be getting the address of the model we want from the collection and then put it in _selectedModel
}

But that doesn't work, it gives a segfault...
So I made this to check if my .getModels command works and yes, it only crashes at the last std::cout, the first two work.
void MonkeyShell::debugCommand() {
    MonkeyModel test = _collection.getModels().at(0);
    MonkeyModel* test_p = &test;
    _selectedModel = &_collection.getModels().at(0);

    std::cout << "test of .getModels().at(0) " << test.getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test of &.getModels().at(0) " << test_p->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of _selectedModel: " << _selectedModel << std::endl;
}

So now I end up here, wondering if the fact that the vector of models is private to the _collection would make the pointer somehow destroy itself ?

My crystal ball thinks that MonkeyCollection::getModels() returns a copy of something rather than a reference to it, so you end up with a dangling pointer.

Welcome to SO. Please try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. It is extremely confusing and hard to understand what you are even asking in your post.

@molbdnilo this is what getModels is pretty much:
Collection MonkeyCollection::getModels() {
    return _models;
}```

_models being an std::vector<MonkeyModels>

@AndréLehto Thanks and sorry for the confusion ! Basically, I am trying to get the address of an element from a vector stored in a class, but whenever accessing it directly it crashes.

Such clarifications go into the question body as an edit, but it sure looks like you are returning a copy and not a reference.

@GAlbert If that's how getModels is then Andre Lehto is exactly right. You are returning a copy of the model, storing a pointer to it, and then the copy gets destroyed. Change getModels to this Collection& MonkeyCollection::getModels(). Now your function returns a reference to the original not a copy. Also note that you would have exactly the same problem in C (but you would not have the reference based solution).

@GAlbert I very much doubt that your code uses the type "c++ Collection". Is the return type std::vector<MonkeyModel> (bad) or std::vector<MonkeyModel>& (good)?

@Botje well since I am trying to get the pointer of only one of the elements inside the array of models, I thought I could simply get the models existing in the _collection (so a copy I guess ?) and then get the address of the desired index ?

@GAlbert No, when the vector is copied so are all it's elements, so you end up with a pointer to an object in a vector that has been destoyed.

@molbdnilo oh my bad i forgot about using Collection = std::vector<MonkeyModel>;

@john oh damn, thanks for the clarification john, I had a feeling something like this was happening but wasn't sure exactly where.

Save yourself some headaches and store the index of the selected item instead of its address.

Or don't even use a std::vector, and use a std::unordered_map, then you can give each model a unique instance identifier you can used to look it up later. Even indices can go stale if the content of your vector changes.

C++ (and the C++ std library) defaults to value based semantics.  A std::vector<X> is a value.  If you create a copy of it, you also copy all of its contents.
_selectedModel = &_collection.getModels().at(0);

the function getModels() used here returns a std::vector by value.  So a temporary copy of the vector is created.  You then call .at(0) on it, giving a reference to the first element of that temporary copy, then do & to get the address of the first element of a temporary copy, store that address in _selectedModel.
The statement then finishes.  When a C++ statement finishes, temporary objects are generally destroyed.  So you have a dangling pointer.
 modelNumber = std::stoi(modelNumberString) - 1;
 _selectedModel = &_collection.getModels().at(modelNumber);

This is an example of a DRY (don't repeat yourself) failure.  The data modelNumber and the _selectedModel fields repeat the same information.
In your case modelNumber is a local variable, so you soon forget it.  But consider remembering the modelNumber instead of the _selectedModel.
The cost to go from modelNumber to _selectedModel is low.  And pointers into std::vectors are dangerous, because std::vector manages the memory they live in - seemingly unrelated operations could invalidate them.
MonkeyModel const* getSelectedModel() const {
  if (m_collection.size() >= modelNumber)
    return nullptr;
  return &(m_collection[modelNumber]);
}
MonkeyModel* getSelectedModel() {
  return const_cast<MonkeyModel*>(
    const_cast<MonkeyShell const*>(this)->getSelectedModel()
  );
}

(the const-cast implementation is an attempt to DRY as well).
Now implement MonkeyModel& MonkeyCollection::operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i)& and MonkeyModel const& MonkeyCollection::operator[](std::ptrdiff_t i) const&.  Make sure you don't mess up and return a reference to a temporary!
